Spring-Boot, Hibernate, MySql Hikari Pool shuts down without error
I have some issue regarding database connection. My application started with docker, and wants to connect to a mysql database, that also started with docker. The problem is, that as soon as HikariPool init it shuts down immediately without any errors, please see logs.
FYI: When I run the application from IDEA, the MYSQL with docker, everything works properly, the HikariPool does not gets dropped.
  application:
    image: com.moovie.info.service/application
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
      - cache
      - database
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://database:3306/statistics?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: secret
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: update
      LOGGING_LEVEL: TRACE
    networks:
      - application

  database:
    hostname: database
    image: mysql:8.4.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: statictics
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    networks:
      - application

networks:
  application:
    name: 'application'

build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'

    id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.36.0'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.1.2'
}

group = 'com.moovie.info.service'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa',
                   'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web',
                   'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis',
                   'redis.clients:jedis',
                   'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docker-compose',
                   'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.4.0'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.32'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

shadowJar {
    zip64 true
}

docker {
    def dockerName = "${project.group}/${project.name}".toLowerCase()

    name dockerName

    dockerfile file('docker/Dockerfile')
    files shadowJar.archiveFile.get(),
            buildArgs([
                    jarFileName   : "${shadowJar.archiveFileName.get()}"
            ])
}

dockerPrepare {
    dependsOn shadowJar
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.movie.info.service.application.web.Application'
        )
    }
}

java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}

Spring log:
2024-05-23T09:19:45.660Z  INFO   --- [           main] c.m.i.s.application.web.Application      : Starting Application using Java 17.0.2 with PID 7 (/app.jar started by root in /)
2024-05-23T09:19:45.665Z  INFO   --- [           main] c.m.i.s.application.web.Application      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-05-23T09:19:46.406Z  INFO   --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-05-23T09:19:46.534Z  INFO   --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 111 ms. Found 1 Redis repository interface.
2024-05-23T09:19:46.539Z  INFO   --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-05-23T09:19:46.590Z  INFO   --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 46 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interface.
2024-05-23T09:19:47.387Z  INFO   --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-05-23T09:19:47.422Z  INFO   --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version [WORKING]
2024-05-23T09:19:47.446Z  INFO   --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-05-23T09:19:47.659Z  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-05-23T09:19:47.687Z  INFO   --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-05-23T09:19:47.888Z  INFO   --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@111cba40
2024-05-23T09:19:47.891Z  INFO   --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-05-23T09:19:48.757Z  INFO   --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-05-23T09:19:48.807Z  INFO   --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-05-23T09:19:49.672Z  INFO   --- [           main] c.m.i.s.application.web.Application      : Started Application in 4.216 seconds (process running for 4.655)
2024-05-23T09:19:49.693Z  INFO   --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-05-23T09:19:49.697Z  INFO   --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-05-23T09:19:49.705Z  INFO   --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Can you please help me to solve?

Looking at the snippet you posted there is no servlet container available thus nothing will start. How did you build your jar? Please add your full build.gradle to the question.

hi, thank you for your comment, included the build.gradle

Remove the shadow jar stuff. Spring Boot already builds a jar that you can run. You should let dockerPrepare depend on bootJar and ditch the shadowJar task.
